# error using sms_advanced plugin in my flutter project

Tags: flutter

I want to get the SMS' list in my flutter phone application. I use sms_advanced in my project:

In pubspec.yaml:

```
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  sms_advanced: ^1.0.2
...
```

In android manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

I `import 'package:sms_advanced/sms_advanced.dart'`;

Then in order to get the messages list in my async method I have the following code:

```
   SmsQuery query = new SmsQuery();
 
   List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.getAllSms;
```

But I have an error which is:

> MissingPluginException(Noimplementation found for method getInbox on
> channel plugins.elyudde.com/querySMS).

What problem causes this problem and how may I fix it?
I tested some methosd like the following terminal commands, but none of them solved my issue:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you hadn't considered the last part of `sms_advanced` package readme file:

> Android Integration
>
> Activity Changes
>
> Note that `sms_advanced`
> requires the use of a `FragmentActivity` instead of an `Activity`. To
> update your application:
>
> If you are using `FlutterActivity` directly, change it to
> `FlutterFragmentActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.
>
> - If you are using a custom activity, update your `MainActivity.java`:
>
>   ```
>     import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
>
>     public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
>         // ...
>     }
>   ```
> - or MainActivity.kt:
>
>   ```
>     import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
>
>     class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
>         // ...
>     }
>   ```
>
> to inherit from `FlutterFragmentActivity`.