# Getting error when using flutter sms_advanced package

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

hi I am trying to use sms_advanced package in flutter application , but getting this Error :
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getInbox on channel plugins.elyudde.com/querySMS)

I just used the same code which was provided in Example part of the package .
but I provide the code here any ways :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms_advanced/sms_advanced.dart';

class SmsAdvancedPackage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SmsAdvancedPackage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SmsAdvancedPackage> createState() => _SmsAdvancedPackageState();
}

class _SmsAdvancedPackageState extends State<SmsAdvancedPackage> {
  final SmsQuery query = SmsQuery();
  List<SmsThread> threads = [];
  List<SmsMessage> messages = [];

  Future<void> updateMessages() async {
    messages = await query.querySms();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    query.querySms().then((value) {
      messages = value;
      print(value);
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 250,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        minVerticalPadding: 8,
                        minLeadingWidth: 4,
                        title: Container(
                            decoration:
                                BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                            child: Text(messages[index].body ?? 'empty')),
                        subtitle:
                            Text(messages[index].date.toString() ?? 'empty'),
                      ),
                      const Divider(),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => updateMessages(),
              child: Text(
                'Update Messages',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have to say I have already tried flutter clean / flutter run / stopped application fully and started again / cache clearing .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This error can has been disscussed in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976559/error-using-sms-advanced-plugin-in-my-flutter-project